# Run AmpScript outside email body

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is there a way to run an ampScript outside email bodies?
SSJS is not enabled on my account and I am looking for a way to run the ampScript without sending any email.

Answer (score 1):

AMPScript will run in a [**landing**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/landing_pages/) or [**microsite**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/microsites/) pages.

[**Send Preview**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/send_an_email/send_preview/) will also run the AMPScript -- in [**Content Builder**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/content_builder/getting_started_with_content_builder/) or [**Classic Content**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/).

Comment: will the Send Preview solution work to update a profile attribute?